# ubuntu 20.04 update error

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I can't update the patches below . I get an error. How to solve this?

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libqt5quick5: Depends: libqt5qml5 (>= 5.12.4) but it is not installed
              Depends: qtbase-abi-5-12-8 but it is a virtual package
              Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-12-8 but it is a virtual package
libqt5webchannel5: Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.8+dfsg~) but 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 is installed
                   Depends: libqt5qml5 (>= 5.12.4) but it is not installed
                   Depends: qtbase-abi-5-12-8 but it is a virtual package
libqt5webkit5: Depends: libicu66 (>= 66.1-1~) but 66.1-2ubuntu2 is installed
               Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but 8c-2ubuntu8 is installed
               Depends: libqt5qml5 (>= 5.12.4) but it is not installed
               Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 9) but 10-20200411-0ubuntu1 is installed
               Depends: qtbase-abi-5-12-8 but it is a virtual package
               Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-12-8 but it is a virtual package
               Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1 is installed
```

Comment: What happens when you disable third party repositories, or run the `apt-get install -f` command as indicated?

Comment: no use coming like this                                                                              E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Comment: Well, you would use `sudo apt-get install -f`